# Web API - How to access a API using a token

Tags: c#, rest, web-applications, webapi

I am new and learning web APIs.

This is a sample API that provides access to a books database.

There are 2 sample API operations available for 2 databases, say ABC and XYZ.

`/api/{abc or xyz}/books` This returns the books that are available.

`/api/{abc or xyz}/book/{ID}` This returns the details of a single book
To access this API you'll require an API token.

Also just like any real world API these may be flakey at times.

I want to Build a web app to allow customers to get the cheapest price for books from these two providers in C#.

The API token provided to you should not be exposed to the public.
Supply the following token in the header to access the API:

```
x-access-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have created a controller with:

```
public class MoviesController : ApiController
{
Movies[] movies = new Movies[]
{
    new Movies { Id = 1, Name = "Star Wars", Category = "Action", Price = 1 },
    new Movies { Id = 2, Name = "Spiderman", Category = "Action", Price = 3.75M },
    new Movies { Id = 3, Name = "Bridget Bones", Category = "Comedy", Price = 16.99M }
};

public IEnumerable<Movies> GetAllProducts()
{
    return movies;
}

public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    var movie = movies.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(movie);
}
```

}

A model class with

```
public class Movies
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

}

and my view as:

```
<body>
<div>
<h2>All Movies</h2>
<ul id="movies" />
</div>
<div>
<h2>Search by ID</h2>
<input type="text" id="movieId" size="5" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
<p id="movie" />
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">/script>
<script>
 var uri = 'api/movies';
 $(document).ready(function () {
 // Send an AJAX request
 $.getJSON(uri)
  .done(function (data) {
    // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
      // Add a list item for the product.
      $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#movies'));
    });
  });
 });

function formatItem(item) {
return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
}

function find() {
var id = $('#movieId').val();
$.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
  .done(function (data) {
    $('#movie').text(formatItem(data));
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    $('#movie').text('Error: ' + err);
  });
  }
  </script>
```

I don't understand how to use the token authentication for this. Lets's say I want to supply the following token in the header to access the API `x-access-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` How do I go about it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into [OAuth2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-ca/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth). Also, do some research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Token based authentication using ASP.Net Web API 2 and OWIN.

Here is the [link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) with step by step instructions of how to implement it.

Best of Luck..!!!

Please don't forget to mark it as "Answer" if it helps you..

Comment: Appreciate your reply @AKR. I have gone through this link is not quiet what I am looking for. I came across this [link] (http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/) wanted to confirm if this authentication is a right method to what i want to achieve? Also how can i compare a book or a movie based on ID from different sources(sites)

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve.I am not quite sure about your requirements so,I can't recommend which one is best for you.But just couple of thoughts - In the link that I sent,the token is generated by the framework,not us.But the one you mentioned ,it looks like we write the code to generate the token. I doubt whether I understand the second question. Are you talking about comparing two objects of same type(Example:Book1 with Book2)?

Comment: I don't understand how to use the token authentication. Lets's say I want to supply the following token in the header to access the API x-access-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx How do i go about it? This app would work like skyscanner. Your from and to gets compared from different sites(via api) and fetches the cheapest fares and puts it to display. I want to build an app of similar kind. I will enter an id say 5 which is the id for movie star wars, it compares through different sites (via api) and should fetch me the cheapest price of that movie and display. how is this comparison happening.